# Зацикливание

Tags: while, циклы, javascript

Надо было зациклить одну функцию. Попробовал такие варианты:

1. while(true) - неудачно, всё зависало
2. while(true) запущенный в web workers - воркеры не поддерживают DOM
3. Попробовал "схитрить" и написал функцию:

   function abc() {

   //Действия функции

   abc();

}

Таким образом хотел добиться зацикливания функции. Неудачно. Действия выполнились один раз, а потом Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Все варианты оказались неудачны. Больше в голову ничего не пришло. Может вы подскажите?

Comment: не до конца понял задачу, но по-моему вы хотите этого:

    setTimeout(function loop(){
        console.log('looping');
        setTimeout(loop, 500);
    }, 500)

Comment: зависание при while(true) связано с тем, что функция выполняется в главном потоке, и пока она не закончит выполняться, "зависание" не пройдет. Я так понимаю, вы совсем новичок в JS, по этому немного распишу то, что написал #Spectre в предыдущем комментарии.
Есть функция `setTimeout(function,timeout)` , которая выполняет заданную function через timeout миллисекунд. Используя ее для того что бы "зациклить" функцию, вы избежите "зависания"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант есть еще setInterval()

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    //ваш код    
}, 100);
```

Ваш код будет выполняться с периодичностью 100 мс.
Остановить выполнение можно будет так

```
clearInterval(interval);
```